# MySQL Pivot rows to columns for a similar record

Tags: sql, mysql, database, pivot

I have got two tables:

1. tbl_sms
2. tbl_bids

The above two table holds something like this:

### tbl_sms:

```
Post_ID | User_ID | SMS_Sent_DT
---------------------------------
123     |   007   |   2010-05-14 10:15:25
123     |   008   |   2010-05-14 10:18:32
123     |   009   |   2010-05-14 10:23:05
123     |   010   |   2010-05-14 10:23:06
```

### tbl_bids:

```
Post_ID | User_ID | Bid_DT
--------------------------
123     |   010   |   2010-05-14 10:27:25
123     |   008   |   2010-05-14 10:28:32
123     |   009   |  2010-05-14 10:28:47
123     |   007   |   2010-05-14 10:35:06
```

With those two tables I'm trying to achieve the following:

```
Post_ID | First_BID_Time | First_BID_SMS_TIME | Second_BID_Time | Second_BID_SMS_Time | Third_BID_Time | Third_BID_SMS_Time
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123     | 2010-05-14 10:27:25 | 2010-05-14 10:23:06 | 2010-05-14 10:28:32 | 2010-05-14 10:18:32 | 2010-05-14 10:28:47 | 2010-05-14 10:23:05
```

---

The query I had written is:

```
   SELECT b.post_id,
          sms.message_sent_at as notif_sent1,
          b.message_sent_at as notif_accepted1,
          DATEDIFF(b.message_sent_at, sms.message_sent_at) AS delay1
     FROM tbl_bids b
LEFT JOIN tbl_sms_status sms ON (sms.jobid = b.post_id AND b.user_id = sms.userid)
    WHERE b.post_id = sms.jobid
 ORDER BY b.post_id ASC
```

That gives me the correct result but they are not pivoted the way I want it to be.

Can please someone help me out with this one. I welcome any solution be it a full lengthy query or a procedure.

Comment: MySQL lacks the analytic/windowing/ranking functionality most would use to get the BID/SMS value to rank appropriately.  It'd be far more scalable *not* to pivot this query, because subsequent `post_id` values might not have 2nd/3rd/4th/5th/etc values

Comment: that's not a problem .. a NULL would be added to those columns

Comment: The query you have written does not seem to be targeted at producing your desired result. Do you need help with producing the result or with the output of the query?

Comment: Yes, I do. Thanks.

I know my query doesn't yield the desired results and need a solution be it a complex query or a simple procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server this would be easy to accomplish using a `ROW_NUMBER()` function or `CROSS APPLY` construct. In MySQL this is [harder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql).

One solution is to [emulate ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1440#104) using variables. This way it is possible to return the bids for each post id ranked on bid time, and get the user_ids. From there on it is an easy matter to LEFT JOIN the SMS time to the post_id/user_id combination. Following the example in the link, the code will be something like:

```
SELECT tmp.Post_ID, tmp.ranking, tmp.user_ID, tmp.Bid_DT, s.SMS_DT
FROM ( 
  SELECT 
    b.Post_ID, b.user_ID, b.Bid_DT, 
    IF( @prev <> ID, @rownum := 1, @rownum := @rownum+1 ) AS ranking, 
    @prev := ID 
  FROM tbl_bids b 
  JOIN (SELECT @rownum := NULL, @prev := 0) AS r 
  ORDER BY b.Post_ID, b.BID_DT 
) AS tmp
LEFT JOIN tbl_sms s
  ON tmp.Post_ID = s.Post_ID AND tmp.user_ID = s.user_ID 
WHERE tmp.rank <= 3 -- Top 3, adjust when more are necessary 
ORDER BY post_ID, ranking;
```

You'll then have an output like this:

```
Post_ID | Ranking  | User_ID | Bid_DT                 | SMS_DT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
123     |    1     |   010   |   2010-05-14 10:27:25  | 2010-05-14 10:23:06
123     |    2     |   008   |   2010-05-14 10:28:32  | ....
123     |    3     |   009   |   2010-05-14 10:28:47  | ....
123     |    4     |   007   |   2010-05-14 10:35:06  | ....
124     |    1     | .......
```

You can store this result in a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE RankedBids(Post_ID INTEGER, Ranking INTEGER, User_ID INTEGER, Bid_DT DATETIME, SMS_DT DATETIME)
INSERT INTO Rankedbids SELECT.... (use above query)
```

Unfortunately due to a [MySQL limitation](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=10327) you can't use multiple references to the same temporary table in a query, so you'll have to split out this table by ranking:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE RankedBids1(Post_ID INTEGER, User_ID INTEGER, Bid_DT DATETIME, SMS_DT DATETIME)
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE RankedBids2....
INSERT INTO Rankedbids1 SELECT Post_ID, User_ID, Bid_DT, SMS_DT FROM RankedBids WHERE Ranking = 1
INSERT INTO RankedBids2...
```

If the recordset is very large, it pays off to assign a (primary key) index on Post_ID to speed up the pivoting query.

Now you can pivot this data:

```
SELECT R1.Post_ID, R1.Bid_DT AS Bid_DT1, R1.SMS_DT AS SMS_DT1 .... 
FROM RankedBids1 R1
LEFT JOIN RankedBids2 R2 ON R1.Post_ID = R2.Post_ID
LEFT JOIN RankedBids3 R3 ON ........
```

OMG Ponies has a point though, it's more scalable to build your system around an unpivoted table. So if you don't need to pivot, don't.

Comment: Thanks LittleGreen ... I will try this solution and will get back to you soon. Thanks again

Comment: Anyway, I made that query run but there seem to be a problem in the last query which actually maps out the result: here it is



[SQL] SELECT 
 R1.Post_ID, 
 R1.Bid_DT AS Bid_DT1, 
 R1.SMS_DT AS SMS_DT1,
 R2.Bid_DT AS Bid_DT2, 
 R2.SMS_DT AS SMS_DT2,
 R3.Bid_DT AS Bid_DT3, 
 R3.SMS_DT AS SMS_DT3
FROM 
 RankedBids R1
LEFT JOIN 
 RankedBids R2 ON (R1.Post_ID = R2.Post_ID AND R2.Ranking = 2)
LEFT JOIN 
 RankedBids R3 ON (R1.Post_ID = R3.Post_ID AND R3.Ranking = 3)
WHERE R1.Ranking = 1;


[Err] 1137 - Can't reopen table: 'R1'

Comment: Annoyingly, in MySQL you can't have multiple references to a temporary table in the same query. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=10327 I didn't know that. You can work around that by copying the RankedBids result out into separate temporary tables RankedBids1, RankedBids2, RankedBids3... (possibly filtered on Ranking to conserve space) and joining on that. Pretty non-optimal but hey when it works...

Comment: I tweak things and made it work .. I created a table since I needed one. Thanks alot